# Disappear image with style blur HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need a picture that some time fade out stylish blur, can i do with html, javascript and css just?

I have this simple code but i want the style:

```
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.setTimeout("document.getElementById('something').style.display='none';", 1000);
</script>
<img id="something" src="error.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt="" />
</head>
```

Thanks

Comment: you want it to fade out? is that what you mean?

Comment: Yes Dory, i made the change to my question, thanks

Comment: np, see my answer bellow, use either pure javascript or jQuery...jQuery is a very handy tool, I suggest you start using it..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use jQuery which is easier.

But here is pure javascript:

```
<img id="something" src="error.png" width="100" height="100" border="0" alt=""  onclick="fade(document.getElementById('something')"/>


<script>
function fade(element) {
    var op = 1;  // initial opacity
    var timer = setInterval(function () {
        if (op <= 0.1){
            clearInterval(timer);
            element.style.display = 'none';
        }
        element.style.opacity = op;
        element.style.filter = 'alpha(opacity=' + op * 100 + ")";
        op -= op * 0.1;
    }, 50);
}
```

or using jQuery (include jQuery first then...)

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 function fade(element) {
     $("#something").fadeOut(1000);
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 4):

#### CSS using `animation`

If you want to use CSS, you can `animation` property. Add all prefixes to the CSS

```
#something:hover {
    -webkit-animation: disappear 0.5s ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
}

@-webkit-keyframes disappear{
    0% {opacity: 1}
    100% { opacity: 0}
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/erjf5/)

#### CSS using `transition`

You can also use `transition` if you want just a simple fadeout

```
#something {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

#something:hover {
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/djJ9k/)

#### Using jQuery

```
$('img#something').delay(1000).fadeOut(1000);
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/PNmFb/)

### *Edit*

#### CSS Using `filter` property

After some time, you can also use CSS3 `filter` property. Its only supported by `-webkit` for now, but others will implement it soon.

```
#something {
    transition: all 1s; 
}
#something:hover {
    -webkit-filter: opacity(0%);
    filter: opacity(0%); /* Official version - without prefixes */
    /* -moz (gecko) -o -ms dont support it, for now. IE does have an */
    /* unofficial version of filter from IE4 to IE9*/
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/metacode/djChj/)

[Check out more awesome uses of CSS3 `filter`](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/say-hello-to-css3-filters/)

[Check out IE filter here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms532847%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As said Sourabh, with pure css you can do it with animation, if you really want a blur effect , I would do it like this :

```
#something:hover {
    -webkit-animation: disappear 0.5s 1 ease-in-out;
}

@-webkit-keyframes disappear{
    0% {opacity: 1; -webkit-filter: blur(0px);}
    100% { opacity: 0; -webkit-filter: blur(10px);}
}
```

I think filters work only on webkit browsers (safari - chrome)